# XAMPP showing errors after fresh Windows Installation

Tags: apache, installation, xampp

I had XAMPP installed in D:/ drive (HDD 500GB) while I had to do a fresh installation of windows 10 in C:/ Drive (SSD 128GB).
I didnot change anything in D:/ drive before or after installation of windows. yet When I open the XAMPP interface and start apache it shows following error log.

**Apache Error Log**
[Mon Nov 29 22:47:59.081101 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 1388:tid 604] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) enter code here enter code hereserver certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[Mon Nov 29 22:47:59.159264 2021] [core:warn] [pid 1388:tid 604] AH00098: pid file E:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Mon Nov 29 22:47:59.163263 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 1388:tid 604] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0

[Mon Nov 29 22:47:59.171261 2021] [:emerg] [pid 1388:tid 604] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the quickest solution is to do a fresh install of XAMPP.

It pretty easy to transfer the XAMPP htdocs folder which contains your lifetime of code, it just simply copy and paste the htdocs folder into a new install of XAMPP.

For your databases it's pretty simple also:

```
Copy all your self created databases folders that are located in xampp/mysql/data

Copy ibdata1 file located in in xampp/mysql/data

Paste your database folders and the ibdata1 file into the xampp/mysql/data on a new install of XAMPP

done !
```